# Editable ListViewByQuery

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2010, dataviewwebpart

I used a LVBQ in a visual webpart. The list is displayed successfully and the filter applied using the Query is working without any problem.

Now, I want to edit the items displayed by the listview. The LVBQ appears to be a read only solution though.

I want it to be modified and I think there's a solution but I don't know what it is exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

there is some code for displaying my list using a LVBQ:

```
ListViewByQuery listview = new ListViewByQuery();
                    if (liste != null)
                    {
                        listview.List = liste;
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery(listview.List.DefaultView);
                        query.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\"Created\"/><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today OffsetDays=\"-7\" /></Value></Geq></Where>";
                        listview.Query = query;
                    }
                    Controls.AddAt(0, listview);
```

So, To enlarge the possibility of having other solutions i say that what i am working on is simply to display a list in a visual webpart with the ability to edit its items.

Comment: I tried a GridView, and succeded in adding an edit control to the list displayed but it only provides textfields however i want to edit a dropdownlist. Also, the listviewbyquery has a better look than the gridview. So, i am asking again if it is possible to make a listviewbyquery editable ??

Comment: The LVBQ approach appears to be a read only solution. it has a likable display than the one from the gridview but i can't just edit the items directly from it and i think it is doable i just don't know how. Any help ?